# Gmail send with OAuth

Tags: genexus

Hi I'm trying to configure a Gmail account for enabling the OAuth module on Genexus

Anybody know the detalled values required on the OAuth consent screen ??

I've tried with diferent values but I always get an error when trying the step 11 included in the document :

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?50408,Google+OAuth+2.0+process+for+emails%3A+Generation+and+data+collection+by+the+Administrator

Any help will be welcome

Thanks